# Как исправить данную ошибку cs0117 в скрипте на юнити?

Tags: unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ошибка cs0117 на юнити в скрипте.
Не знаю как исправить, помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: покажите в документации на то, что есть такой метод в таком типе класса?

Comment: Вроде бы все правильно говорит. В том скрипте нет таких методов.

Answer (score 0):

Я исправил, надо было процесинг обновить:-)